# Replace a text by shell programming

Tags: shell, replace

i have more than 1000 files and want to replace a special text in all of them with another phrase.

how can i do it by shell script in linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' *.txt
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    cp $file $file.tmp
    cat $file.tmp | sed 's/foo/bar/g' > $file
done
```

Comment: You can use `-i` to edit the files in place, so there is neither a need for a temporary file nor for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bash

```
for file in *.txt
do
   while read -r line
   do
     case "$line" in
       "*pattern*") line="${line//pattern/new}";;
     esac
     echo "$line"
   done <"$file" > t
   mv t "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed).